# Hats hats hats! Winter Bash 2014

Tags: discussion

Alright, folks, Winter Bash 2014 is coming. Do we want to be this:

[image]

Or do we want to be this

[image]

I don't know about you, but I'm leaning toward option 2. Not to bias your opinion.

Note if we do it, you can always opt out individually. Or if there is a compelling reason why we, as a site, shouldn't get our hat on, please voice your opinion. I declare this a no judgement zone. =) Okay, maybe a small-amount-of-judgement zone, but I'm sure I can hold it together.

What say you?

> For those confused, the first picture is the band Men Without Hats (they did the Safety Dance). 
>  
>  The second picture is a lot of hats. I hope you didn't need the spoiler for that one...

Comment: I win hahahaha!

Answer (score 1):

It's a yes from me to winter headgear. We participated last year - I didn't hear any objections then, so I'm not aware of any reason to say no this time.